# Build GTK+ application in Ada - GtkAda

Tags: gtk3, ada

I'm trying to develop to the first time a `GTK+ application` in `Ada`, with `GtkAda`. I installed it, and I could build a `Hello World` application from the "Simple Window" template proposed by `GPS`.

But, when I want to run it, I become an error popup with this message:

> "gdk_device_get_last_event_window" could not be found in the DLL "[path_to_my_project]\obj\main.exe".

It was linked with the static library. If I try to link with the `relocatable` library (using GPS scenario variable LIBRARY_TYPE), I got almost the same error:

> "gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf" [...]

This second error appears too if I try to launch sample applications (testgtk.exe or test_rtree.exe) from [gtkada_dir]\share\examples\gtkada\testgtk.

So, did I missed something at the installation of GtkAda?

> I run `Windows 8.1`, I installed GtkAda into the default folder
>   (`C:\GtkAda` - note I tried to install it into `C:\GNAT\2016` too, but the
>   problem is the same).
>
> My PATH includes `C:\GtkAda\bin;C:\GtkAda\lib`, I added another
>   environment variable `ADA_PROJECT_PATH=C:\GtkAda\lib\gnat`.

I installed `Gnat` from the latest version (20160515-49).

Any idea to get `GtkAda` applications running?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you use the Alire package manager, install a newer GNAT studio from https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatstudio/releases (click at the Assets link to download the installers) and then install Alire from https://alire.ada.dev/

Once alire is installed just create a new project with gtkada with the commands:

```
alr init --bin holagtk
cd holagtk
alr with gtkada
alr run
```

If you want to upgrade an old project to Alire, you may run the commands:

```
cd oldgtkproject
alr init --in-place --no-skel --bin oldgtkproject
alr with gtkada
alr run
```

You may need to edit the generate project a little bit

> **IMPORTANT:** The gtkada package does not work when your user home path or your project contains whitespaces, ensure you use paths like /home/user1, /opt/gnatstudio, /opt/alire, etc.

Comment: Thank you @carlos-saltos for answering this question. I changed my setup and now run Linux, so I won't try GTK with Ada with Windows anymore; but I'll have a look to Alire, that's something new to me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I find that GtkAda works best with GNAT in Windows when installed in the GNAT directory. In the case of your installation that should be C:\Gnat\2016. Also make sure you add the following line to the beginning of your project file:

with "gtkada";

Comment: Thanks Jim for your suggestions. I tried to install `GtkAda` into `C:\GNAT\2016`, but I had the same problem. I already had `with "gtkada";` in my project files.