how to install gtkada on linux
i can't to install gtkada on my Linux PC. I tried look at the adacore's docs but I can't to understand. please someone can help me to install gtkada.i'm really blocked.
after to have download and unzipgtkada-gpl file,gtk+,pango... i tried to install gtkada with command-line
./configure prefix=/usr/gtkada
make

the installation was done with a : warning : werror = 'argument' '-werror=format-security' is not valid for ada...
I also tried to add PATH variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH like read adacore's docs
when I compile my program gnat tell me gtkada.ads, gtk.ads is not found.
I've gnat version 12.2.0 and my IDE VScode.

If you are ok using the Alire package manager for Ada, you can reference this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785525/9604966

the command once setup is to go into your project that is configured for alire and type: alr with gtkada

You may also need to do: alr get --build gtkada

Please [edit] this question to reflect the progress you've made here.
